# Software development process for a product like MS-Office

Tags: development-process, software

What is the best or most suitable **software development process** to follow when developing products like **Microsoft Office product** (has no specific client)? and Why?

Could it be Waterfall? or a modified one? 
Could it be an agile software development method?

Comment: Can you please be more direct with your question as the response to this will likely be opinionated.

Comment: In general, it's best to ask concrete answers to problems you're actually facing. Generic, theoretical questions tend to lead to extremely broad questions that will be closed as Too Broad, or opinionated answers rather than canonical ones. If your question is put on hold, please edit it until it can be re-opened as on-topic.

Comment: Hi Jon, CodeGnome, 
I guess the question is clear. However, I am going to rephrase it here. 
As you know, when developing a product, this product can be developed for specific customer/s not for public, or it can be developed for all computer users (like Microsoft Office) by selling it to them after it is totally developed and ready to use. Now the concrete question is: What is the good development method for that? (Agile like Scrum, XP, etc or Waterfall methods)

Comment: Hi Yi Wei,  your question still will result in an opinionated answer.  With that said, I would recommend doing some additional research (Garnter and Forrester or something similar) into analysis of software development projects, products created, and methods used and that will give you a better picture of what the industry is currently up to.

Comment: That's the first time I've seen anyone express the opinion that MS-Office was "totally developed and ready to use" when it came onto the market :) That would be a first for Microsoft...

Answer (score 2):

For the choice of development process it does not really matter if there is a paying customer behind it or if it is an investment by upper management with the hope of being able to sell the product later.

If there is no paying customer who came with a concrete set of wishes, there will be someone within the organization who has a strong vision for the product and who can play the role of the customer for the project.
Budgets for products are not obtained from thin air, but someone will have made a proposal to make the investment in the product and probably also have done research on the properties that the product should have.